# stripe api invoice charge is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Here is my stripe subscription:

```
subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve('sub_I4wF')
```

when user downgrade `refund` the unused balance to `customer through refund.`

To create a refund documentation says `In the API call, include the charge ID to refund.`

I tried to get the charge ID from `subscription.latest_invoice`

```
 latest_invoice = Stripe::Invoice.retrieve(subscription.latest_invoice)
```

but charge id is null  `"charge": null,`

```
#<Stripe::Invoice:0x3fc07bb95a20 id=in_1HUmNoHHVd> JSON: {
  "id": "in_1HUmNoHHVdsLap10",
  "object": "invoice",
  "account_country": "AU",
  "account_name": null,
  "amount_due": 0,
  "amount_paid": 0,
  "amount_remaining": 0,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "attempt_count": 0,
  "attempted": true,
  "auto_advance": false,
  "billing_reason": "subscription_update",
  "charge": null,
  "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
  "created": 1600922920,
```

Comment: are you sure, you have charged a customer ? :)

Comment: yes. it works first time.  then charge become null downgrade second time.

Comment: Probably, you need to read this https://groups.google.com/a/lists.stripe.com/g/api-discuss/c/bMNANUQiV2E?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

That Invoice is a zero dollar invoice, so there is no charge because there is nothing to refund.